# MVC Webgrid, is it possible to add css style to a single columns header?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using MVC4 and the WebGrid control.

I need to apply CSS styles to all the columns headers **except for the first column**

Currently my code is:

```
@{
   Webgrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.entrySheet.data);
   grid.GetHtml(columns:Model.columns,headerStyle:"webgridHeader");
 }
```

This applies the css style "webgridHeader" to **all** columns.

Is there anyway to style the indvidual style of each header column header?

I would perfer a non-javascript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how dynamic it should be. But if the amount of columns is fixed, you may get what you want by using `:nth-child(x)` in css. Of course, older browser don't understand that.

Or, if it is just the first column, you can use the pseduo class `:first-child` which is known by many more browsers, even IE7 as far as I know.

Comment: Wow ':first-child' was perfect!